# How to stop timer of an activity from another activity

Tags: java, android, timer, timertask

Right now I have an activity, let's say 'Activity A' that runs the Timer. It is to update my Firebase when the time is up.

```js
timer.scedule(new TimerTask()){
@Override
public void run() {
 notification();
 Firebase areaRef = mAreaRef.child(bKey);
 areaRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
  public void onDataChange(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
   checkData = dataSnapshot.child("data").getValue(Integer.class);
   Integer addData = checkData+1;
  } 

   @Override
  public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

  } 
  });                                                       
 }
},millis);
```

There will be a button at 'Activity B'. When the button is clicked, the timer at 'Activity A' must be stopped.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

There just can be only one "Activity" activated in the same time. Your 'Activity A' can be instead by a service. And then your problem is solved by 'Activity B' directly call service method to stop the timer when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

If your timer task *really* needs to be alive across activities, maybe you should consider use a **[Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)** instead of a timer in specified activity.

Answer (score 0):

1.Change Timer to `CountDownTimer` call `start()` to begin call  `cancel()` to stop.
How to notify Activity A to stop the `CountDownTimer`, you can change SharedPreferences to others way to deal with data notify

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("count", 0);
            if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("stop", false)) {
                timer.cancel();
            } else {
                Log.d("tag", millisUntilFinished / 1000 + "");
            }
        }

        public void onFinish() {

        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        timer.start();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

```html
public class ActivityB extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button mStop;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);
        mStop =(Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
        mStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("count",0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor edit= sharedPreferences.edit();
                edit.putBoolean("stop", true);
                edit.apply();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: May I know why CountDownTimer is used instead of Timer?

Comment: haha,Absolutely you can keep use Timer, CountDownTimer is my favorite(it is just in android.os package),

Comment: Oh? I thought CountDownTimer was used so that every 1 second it will check 'ActivityB' for the sharedpreferences. If it is not the case, is the sharedpreferences an instant action?

Comment: Have you tested your answer? I used "static boolean stopTimer" instead of sharedprefs. ActivityB contained a button set stopTimer=true. onTick contained: if(stopTimer) {timer.cancel(); CancelCounter();}  The function CancelCounter() { myCount++; Toast.makeText(this,""+myCount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);}  In ActivityB a 25sec countdown with 1sec ticks I saw up to 23 toasts pop up when I hit cancel (not 24 because of a bug in CountDownTimer). The variable was set from B, A called the function which is why I saw toasts, but timer.cancel() didn't cancel timer else only one toast would have displayed.

Comment: I will add to my comment that in ActivityA I added a button like the one I put in ActivityB. It's only function was to set stopTimer=true. I also saw multiple toasts appear after I hit that button. This tells me again that the if condition is being met so it calls the counter function but the timer.cancel() inside that same if statement isn't going anything.